# How to use authentication using url variables and a text file

Tags: php, file, passwords

I have a text file named as auth.txt with the following data:

```
pete:quora
admin:pass
quora:test
```

I want to make a php file which take variables as:

```
$_GET['user']

$_GET['pass']
```

check using my txt file I want to echo "success"  if user and pass are in text my file.

else echo "success"

I tried:

```
 <?php

$userN = $_GET['user'];
$passW = $_GET['pass'];
$userlist = file ('auth.txt');
foreach ($userlist as $user) {
    $user_details = explode(':', $user);
    if ($user_details[0] == $userN && $user_details[1] == $passW) {
        $success = true;
        break;
    }
    else {echo "failed";}
}

?>
```

^ This didn't work out

Comment: easier to use a database

Comment: you should mark off your past questions as solved before posting new ones

Comment: but still i wanted to try that :3

Comment: So where do you think you should put the `echo 'success';` then

Comment: Maybe instead of `$success = true;` for example

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks did that :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly tried that didn't work out

Comment: Really?? It should

Comment: Is that really all the code in this script file?

Comment: try it . didn't work out for me ;-;

Comment: Maybe you should show us the form that captures `user` and `pass` then. Or add a `print_r($_GET);` to check you actually have those variables in `$_GET`

Comment: yeah sure take a look https://i.snag.gy/QISasb.jpg

Comment: test every variable, assume nothing, and make sure error checking and display are on.

Comment: why people are so worried about grammar what if someone came on this site from remote area who doesn't know much of English . he will be down voted to like -100 in a week ? :/ . Same goes for Quora but there's only up vote option i think

Comment: @Bitprocon what are you talking about, the edit that I made? To improve it and remove the typos/grammar? I hope not. If so, that's the thanks I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed your code , and I would like to point out that you have to trim the data returned from your auth.txt file in each line as it might contain other characters as new line characters .. etc 
here is the code you shall use for it :

```
$userN = $_GET['user'];
$passW = $_GET['pass'];
$userlist = file ('auth.txt');

foreach ($userlist as $user) {
    $user_details = explode(':', $user);


    if (trim($user_details[0]) == $userN && trim($user_details[1]) == $passW) {
        $success = true;
        ECHO "Success <br />";
        break;
    }
    else {echo "failed <br />";}
}
```

Comment: same . Who did that . Even i got some down vote over my question

Comment: fixing the text file in the first place, would be a better option.

Comment: Nice to know it is working .. and with you , wondering why your question was downgraded .